# Control + C inconsistent behavior

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ctrl

I seem to be having an issue as when I am at home my application detects when I input the Control + C for the c# console command application. But now that I am in the library it is just closing the application and not preventing it from closing like it was at home.

```
static void DetectControlAndCPressed()
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var isCtrlC = e.SpecialKey == ConsoleSpecialKey.ControlC;
            var isCtrlBreak = e.SpecialKey == ConsoleSpecialKey.ControlBreak;
            if (isCtrlC)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                validateUsersInput(null);
            }
        };

static string validateUsersInput(string originalinput)
    {
        if (originalinput == null)
        {
            originalinput = "Control + C";
            if (Globals.errorMessageDisplayed == false)
            {
                Globals.errorMessageDisplayed = true;
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: No Value Detected");

                return originalinput;
            }
            return originalinput;
        }
        else
        {
            string userinput = originalinput.ToLower();
            return userinput;
        }
```

I call for the DetectContorlC method before my while loop so it is constantly detecting it. I don't know why me being in a different location would change whether it is getting captured or not.

The only thing I can think of is that I am missing some information from my last save or something, really confusing bug

Comment: What do you mean by "when I am at home" and "when I am at the library"? Are you running the same executable on different computers? Or are you running same executable on the same computer (e.g. your notebook)? Or are you using the same source, but you re-compile it on a different computer? etc.

Comment: @stakx Yeah I am using Visual Studio 2013 in the library and the same exact software at home. It is being compiled through the Visual Studio compiler and both the Library and My Home Computer are desktop Windows

Comment: Are you running from within Visual Studio in both places (i.e. not from the command line in one location but within VS in the other)?  If within VS, are you using the same configuration (Debug/Release/whatever)?  Same platform (x86, Any CPU, etc.)?

Comment: I would speculate it has to do with the order in which event handlers are fired, which is not usually deterministic(among you handlers they are, but when we talk about other handlers outside of your code it is an implementation detail).  The handler that closes the application may sometimes be getting fired before your event handler.

Comment: I rebooted the computer and reloaded from the exact same path and it seems to have fixed it. I think it was getting confused on what directory to compile the application from:/

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted the computer and reloaded from the exact same path and it seems to have fixed it. I think it was getting confused on what directory to compile the application from

This is probably a problem caused by me using my Pen Drive